# ubuntu 12.10 Cannot Play VCD

Tags: 12.10, vlc, vcd

I cannot play VCDs in Ubuntu 12.10. But I can play DVDs. I have done a lot research and found a ton of question and regarding this but none of the solutions worked for me.

Here is what i have tried so far

As i said  i can play DVD but not any VCDs. To  confirm this i have tried different VCDs.
I'm using Vlc.

```
File reading failed:
VLC could not read the file (Input/output error).
File reading failed:
VLC could not read the file (Input/output error).
```

I'm getting above error message when i try to play VCD using Vlc. I can play the same VCD in Windows XP installation (I have installed both Ubuntu and Windows XP).

Then i tried

```
sudo apt-get-install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

And it said i have updated software.

Then tried installing w32codecs which has already installed then some CDFS files

Actually tried most of the solutions and i have been trying for the last one week....

Please do not mark this as a duplicate, because i have tried most of solutions mentioned in ask ubuntu.

Comment: Install libcdio-utils `apt-get install libcdio-utils` and then run `cd-info` which is in that package.  It should scan your drive and tell you if it thinks there is a vcd in the drive. If there is one, then we can focus on the vlc side.